# maven compilation failure when runing mvn:install

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

I'm facing a compilation errors when i try to run `mvn:install`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Maven has not found the Java compiler in your environment.
You'll have to install the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows---> Preferences--->Type(Installed JRE)--> Click(Add)--> Standard Vm's-->Next-->Click(Directory)-->(Path to your JDK or JRE)--> Select the JDK --> Try Again.

Hope this will help.